# Crystal Reports format diagramm series axis

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports Basic from Visual Studio. Now I want to create a 3D-Block Diagram but the series axis has the text from my columns of the dataset.
Here is how my chart preview looks like
[xx http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ba50bf02d0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ba50bf02d0.jpg)

and here is how it is configured in the diagram assistant
[xx http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/214a42822e.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/214a42822e.jpg)

All the texts on the series axis should be formatted like Monday, Tuesday, etc. and not Sum of SimultaneousMissionsWeekDayTable.Monday, Sum of SimultaneousMissionsWeekDayTable.Tuesday.

Somebody any clue......

Answer (score 0):

No worries, it's an easy fix:

1. Go to the **Preview** window
2. Right click on the label itself, and choose **Edit Axis Label**.
3. You'll see the Original Label and the Displayed Label.  Change the Displayed Label to whatever you like.

#### Edit

Thanks for the pictures.  Made it much easier to understand your question.